# Trying to install a pack from source. I get: ImportError: No module named requests Yet the pack is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, open-source

I'm trying to install: https://github.com/rozzac90/pinnacle.git from source.
If I type `sudo python setup.py install` (or `sudo python setup.py configure`) I get:

```
import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

The module is installed, I'm sure. It is in the list of conda installed packs. Also, if I try to import it in other scripts, and

```
python  
>>> import requests
>>>
```

with both python 2 and python3. I get no errors.

I also removed it and installed it again. Same results.

I am using Anaconda with a python3 environment. (I get the same errors in python 2, though.) So I can't use pip commands. I'm running a lubuntu machine, latest version.

Ideas anyone? Thanks in advance !

Comment: try uninstall (maybe both conda and pip) and then reinstall. Usually this fixes something like that

Comment: I read in the documentation that pip is not safe when you are using conda.

Comment: I tried the install and uninstall.Same results.

Comment: try with sudo /[annaconda_python_path]/python setup.py install

Comment: @mm_  , thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggested answer :
The solution was to run the script in the folder where setup.py is located, in general :

Try with

```
sudo /[annaconda_python_path]/python setup.py install
```

Make sure the right environment is active in the terminal.